# HDMI no signal when i run game

Tags: hdmi

Hi I have a raspberry 3 system with recallbox software. the systems works and initiates.
when i run a game the HDMI says no signal. this happened when i changed tv.
i tried 3 different tvs and 4 different hdmi cables . one of the tvs it says troubleshooting to change the resolution.

Comment: Without knowing what the game is the question will be closed due to lack of info (hence my vote).  You need to find out how to set the game resolution - it's trying something not supported by the Pi or TVs / monitors.

Comment: What Raspberry Pi do you use?